# pyinstaller "Failed to execute script"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

(before start, i'm not good at eng.)

i'm making a python application.
everything was completed.
but, pyinstaller don't work well.
the file's name is "shojo.py".
i used this code.

```
pyinstaller -w -F shojo.py
```

and if execute the file,
this window appears.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uucGA.png)

this time, i used this code.

```
pyinstaller -w -F -p D:\python\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin shojo.py
```

but the result was same.
this is the log.

https://github.com/shojoinfo/shojoinfo/blob/master/shojo/source/log%2Ctxt

and i found the file "warn-shojo.txt"

this is the file's contents.

https://github.com/shojoinfo/shojoinfo/blob/master/shojo/source/warn-shojo.txt

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the cause, but from the logs I see you need to give path to install those missing modules.

See here:

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html

Comment: Sorry, but i cant find it. If you know where it is, let me know.

Comment: @dolphine103 The third link you gave in the question gives you that list.